# Does hibernate filter plugin for grails support table join and multiple parameter?

Tags: hibernate, grails, filter

I am learning to use this plugin. By following the steps in grails.org, I successfully applied the filter in single domain class. But I'd like to know whether hibernate  filter support conditions cross two tables.  I list my case's detail information in below. Could you give some advice?

Backgroud:
**1.** I have below db schema ( the relation between these two table is one Product can have several ProductItems that is one-to-many relationship.)

```
Table : Product
column
------------------------------
id               |  auto_increment
name             | 
create_uid       | the user id create this product
```

Another table : ProductItem

column

---

```
id                | auto_increment
name              |
product_id        |the value specify which product it belongs to
```

**What I want to ?**

when one user access the data, I want to **list product Items created by himself**. But only the product table has "user information who created it".  The result I want is same with executing below sql statement:

```
"
select product_item.id from product_item ,product where   
product_item.product_id=product.id and product.create_uid=xxx
"
```

As the system has already implemented. I'd like to use hibernate filter without changing code.

**What I know?**

From the document, I notice that hibernate filter's definition support "collection" to specify another relation.  But my concern is I don't find any place to specify  condition ("orderItem.order_id = order.id ")

```
class ProductItem{

Product product
static hibernateFilters = {
   secureFilter(condition:'create_uid=5', collection:"product", default:true)   // This doen't work 
}  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not up-to-date if there's any newer and fancy features to handle this in the plugin, but I have formerly used subselects to tackle this case:

```
secureFilter(condition: 'product_id in (select product.id from product where product.create_uid=5)', default: true)
```

Comment: wwwclaes,as you know, we can use parameter in filter's definition. like **secureFilter(condition:"create_uid=:myParam", types:"string")**. But before each usage, we need to specify the param's value. `filter.setParameter('myParam',5)` _I'd like to know whether there existing usage like global variable in programming lauguage_. In the scenario of my question, when I got user's id information after user loged into our system, I can set the param's value there. For other place, they can use directly by specify "default:true".

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you fully. But maybe this will help:

Look at the source of HibernateFilterFilters in the plugin. Override that with your own implementation by copying to your apps conf-dir. Enable filters and set parameters as needed (eg by retrieving them from session, springSecurityService or similar).